# How to configure copy only full backup in veeam?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Application aware full backups and log backups are configured in the veeam settings as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

I want to modify the settings such that full backups are using the copy only mode. However, the perform copy only radio button is only applicable to transaction log (as shown in the section header). How to configure copy only full backup in veeam?

Reason why I want to apply copy only full backup mode is - otherwise (without the copy only mode) the full backup breaks the differential backup chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option confusingly enough means that Veeam will do copy only for the *snapshot full backup*, not the log backups. The GUI is confusing.

I suggest you change that option to "Perform copy only" and then (re)visit the backup history tables to verify that the full snapshot backup is done using copy_only.

I don't have an environment where I can test this, so I consulted a whitepaper I wrote for Veeam 5 years ago. Back then I did have access to an environment so hopefully the information in that WP is correct (it was proof-read as well :-) ).

Here's a quote from that WP:

"As for the “Transaction logs” option, you want to select “Perform copy only” if you perform your own SQL Server backups. This way the Veeam snapshot backup will be seen by SQL Server as a COPY_ONLY backup and will not interfere with any differential backups that you produce in SQL Server. "

You can find it here, https://www.veeam.com/wp-sql-server-backup-with-veeam.html. I think that you can get to the pdf by registering and also get the screenshots that way.

Comment: In the `msdb.dbo.backupset` table, the backup is recorded with `type D` and `is_copy_only 0`. This means that it is not a copy only backup.

Comment: Where can I do this check - `Check the backup history for your Veeam snapshots`? I was expecting that `is_copy_only` value should have been `1` if it was a copy only backup.

Comment: I wrote a whitepaper for Veeam about 5 years ago and I consulted that WP. I added some info in my above answer.

Comment: Looks like the answer is not updated. Please can you check again.

Comment: It is updated now.

Comment: Thanks. By the way there is a type of log backup in SQL server called copy only log backup. This doesn't truncate the transaction log and doesn't affect the log backup chain. Are you sure that the `copy only` option in the Veeam backup tool only refers to copy only Full backup and not also copy only transaction log backup?

Comment: Yes, there are copy only log backups. I'm pretty sure that this option doesn't do that, though. If you read the Texy, it states that Veeam doesn't do log backups att all when you choose this option. But as I said, I don't have access to such an install, so you want to do the final verification.